# rails errorExplanation conflicting with my jquery?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a rails form that is like all rails forms and if anything fails the standard rails error appears:

```
<div id="errorExplanation" class="errorExplanation">
  <h2>2 errors prohibited this account from being saved</h2>
  <p>There were problems with the following fields:</p>
  <ul><li>First Name can't be blank</li>
  <li>Number is not a valid credit card number</li></ul>
</div>
```

But I have some jQuery on the page that needs to popup a spinner when the submit is clicked:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#add_account').click(function(){
    console.log($('#errorExplanation').length);
    $('#spinner').show();
  });
 });
```

But the `console.log` is always 0 and I need the spinner to only appear if there is no `#errorExplanation` on the page.

The `console.log` is telling me there is 0 but there is one so I'm guessing Rails is loading this div on the page after its loaded.

Any ideas how to address this and only show the `#spinner` when there is REALLY no `#errorExplanation` on the page?

Comment: I suspect the click event is firing _before_ rails' form validator.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#add_account').click(function(){
    if(!$('#errorExplanation').length){
        $('#spinner').show();
    }
  });
 });
```

**Edit**:
Use .length to calculate the contents of the div. If `0`, it does not exist.

Edited :-)

Comment: It will only return true if the element exists. http://jsfiddle.net/W2nfx/. TS askes "when there is REALLY no #errorExplanation on the page".